# Capturing IO.put in ExUnit test Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using

```
Task.Supervisor.start_child(Ex.TaskSupervisor, fn ->
  apply(module, function, args)
end)
```

under a `GenServer`'s `handle_info/2` using `Process.send_after/3`.

I am trying to capture the output of the `apply/3` call.

The test modules are very simple

```
  defmodule Hello do
    def perform(), do: IO.puts("Perform!")
    def hello(), do: IO.puts("Hello!")
    def hello(name), do: IO.puts("Hello #{name}!")
  end
```

the test is very basic too

```
 test "use perform/0 function by default" do
    config = [%{cron: "* * * * * *", module: Hello}]

    assert capture_log(fn ->
             Worker.start_link(config)
             Process.sleep(1200)
           end) == "Perform!"
  end
```

when I run the test, it does log on to the console for 'Perform!'

```
Perform!


  1) test use perform/0 function by default (Ex.WorkerTest)
     test/ex_scheduler/worker_test.exs:13
     Assertion with == failed
     code:  assert capture_log(fn ->
              Worker.start_link(config)
              Process.sleep(1200)
            end) == "Perform!"
     left:  ""
     right: "Perform!"
```

when this runs `Worker.start_link(config)` it just calls handle_info and `IO.puts` but it's not coming in capture_log/capture_io, I have tried both.

any help would be wonderful

Comment: capture_log only captures from the Logger module. Use that instead of IO.puts

Comment: The reason why `capture_io` doesn't work is because by default it works on the process level, and the process calling `IO.puts` is your `Worker` or genserver, not your test process. I'm not sure if it could work by setting a different `device` (name of the process), but `Logger` and `capture_log` seems like better options here.